# Needing to remove nav-above box from stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet

[Dots & Dashes](http://dotsanddashes.co.uk/) currently has a rather unsightly `nav-above` box on its blog pages, as seen above the below post:

http://dotsanddashes.co.uk/blog/huge-moves-savage-sister/

Having inspected the element on Chrome, it seems easy enough to remove it via HTML, although I'm struggling to find all the applicable bits in the CSS stylesheet... I *think/* hope this is a pretty rudimentary fix, for which I apologise in advance, but my grasp of CSS is slightly dodgy in truth..!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it with CSS using the rule:

```
#nav-above {
    display: none;
}
```

This will remove it from the flow of the page so things should appear the same as deleting from the DOM tree in the Chrome inspector.

Note that the relevant source and images etc are still downloaded by users so ideally you should actually remove it from the source if you no longer want it.

Comment: Brilliant – thank you! But where exactly would I insert that piece of code? Again, excuse my ignorance...

Comment: Line 1499 in your stylesheet - get rid of `display:block`, this is overriding the `display:none` above it.

Comment: Thanks – all sorted now. Fantastic!